# Playing Sound Effect in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using following code to play an audio file, but I get program crashes at the second line of the code. What could be the problem?

Here is the code I am using:

```
Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/bonk.mp3");
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

And the error I am getting when I run this code is:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message when this crashes?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using a `.wav` file instead of an `.mp3` file for your sound effect?

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx) for `SoundEffect.FromStream` has a note about sound file requirements:

> The Stream object must point to the head of a valid PCM **wave** file.
>   Also, this **wave** file must be in the RIFF bitstream format.
>
> The audio format has the following restrictions:
>
> - Must be a PCM **wave** file
> - Can only be mono or stereo
> - Must be 8 or 16 bit
> - Sample rate must be between 8,000 Hz and 48,000 Hz

Answer (score 3):

the problem with your solution is that soundeffect doesnot play .mp3 file you need to use .wav to use soundeffect..